# Django: can we load dict directly to the database using django ORM

Tags: python, django, orm

I have lot of dict data like `{{'title':'stackoverflow'}}` where the keys are similar to the table column names. i want to load all the dict directly to the database using the django ORM.

Comment: Similar or identical? Do you have an existing (legacy) database that you want to use in a Django project? In either case you should have models, please include them.

Comment: I am using SQLite and defined the models

Comment: You probably want to format your data as e.g. json and use the [loaddata](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/django-admin/#loaddata) command.

Comment: I want to do it in a django views

Answer (score 0):

Some databases, such as postgreSQL have built in support for complex types such as lists and JSON blocks. Unfortunately SQLite does not. But we can still get it done.

You'll want to create a custom field, that serializes and deserializes the dictionary as JSON for storage and use.

[This](https://medium.com/@philamersune/using-postgresql-jsonfield-in-sqlite-95ad4ad2e5f1) Medium article gives a good overview, and explanation, but the part you're concerned with I've copied below

```
    class JSONField(Field):
        def db_type(self, connection):
            return 'text'

        def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
            if value is not None:
                return self.to_python(value)
            return value

        def to_python(self, value):
            if value is not None:
                try:
                    return json.loads(value)
                except (TypeError, ValueError):
                    return value
            return value

        def get_prep_value(self, value):
            if value is not None:
                return str(json.dumps(value))
            return value

        def value_to_string(self, obj):
            return self.value_from_object(obj)
```